# What component do I need to add my own "Private" electric meter

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, workshop

I am adding a workshop, and upgrading my service from 200A to 400A.  The Shop will get a 200A panel and the existing House panel will be backfed from the main.  I want to bring the new House feeder into the existing meter base and install my own private GE electric meter.  Can I use any serviceable 200A single phase 240V meter such as I might find refurbished on EBAY?  like the dial ones, versus the digital ones?  Does NEC have any rules on installing my own meter?
[image]

I was looking at something like this:
[image]

Comment: Why are you interested in a second meter? Will you be tracking energy usage? Are you renting the house so you wish to charge accordingly for electricity? I think that a standard analog meter would be better since the digital ones could require activation by the power company. I'd recommend getting guidance from the power company to be honest. As long as you're not tampering with the 400 amp meter which your power company uses I don't think they care what you do after the meter.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Power company advice can be of limited value, since they follow a completely different codebook (NESC vs NEC).

Comment: i added an additional sentence to my first comment. This website has some guidance on clearances https://www.buildmyowncabin.com/electrical/installing-new-electrical-service.html

Comment: This seems to have good info https://www.bia.gov/sites/bia.gov/files/assets/public/pdf/idc-037760.pdf

Comment: 200A is overkill for a workshop, whereas all-electric houses frequently exceed 200A of need. **Solution**: a [400A 200/200 meter-main with a mini-panel](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-400-Amp-8-Space-16-Circuit-UG-Feed-Meter-Combo-with-Lever-Bypass-MC0816B1400SDL/300870369) on one side.  One 200A breaker goes straight to the house's main.  The other 200A breaker goes through an 8-space mini-panel and is thru-lugged to the workshop at 200A.  The 8 spaces can be used as needed to feed large loads at the house off the workshop's 200A allocation.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm still interested in hearing why a second meter is desired. Does your suggestion provide a readout for the 200 amp legs individually? I'm just not very familiar with that product.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No, it wouldn't address that, it's just an "oh by the way" PSA like "get BIG panels".

Comment: I want to be able to calculate how much of the power the shop is using.  Even though the occupant is also the shop occupant, we want to be able to split cost for the workshop.  And Harper:  as to 200 A being overkill for a shop... It may be for now with  1200 sqft just on the bottom floor and MANY 240V appliances (two very large 40A welders, 50A CNC plasma cutter, Swamp Cooler, Air Compressor, CNC mill...)

Comment: Harper, as to the different code (NESC vs NEC), YES I am very surprised the power company is splicing up my Giant 500MCM Cu required entrance wires to tiny 4/0 Al wires off the pole...Their answer was: "we are not under NEC..."

Comment: Call an electrician and ask for a quote about your desired plan and they will very quickly say one of a few things: "Yeah, that sounds good" or "That's not legal" or "That's utterly dangerous". This will give you an idea of whether you need to rethink your plan.

Comment: Heck, even pay an electrician to come out and assess your plan (consultation) since you're planning to do it yourself and don't want to trick someone into investing their time talking to you. Like I said, everything after the main power meter is YOUR responsibility.

Comment: @markf  I've seen and done parallel 500 MCM  to 4/0 AL ...  Power company loves free air and diversity in loading.. lol

Comment: Jack: I wonder if the power/heat loss they experience is worth the savings in wire over the years....  prob yes because folks rarely go anywhere near their rated input level of amps.

Comment: @markf, that's exactly it.  Wires flapping in the breeze can shed the heat, so it's not a safety concern; it just comes down to whatever's cheaper for them.  And remember they can track your usage and adjust accordingly.  If you're like the 99% of people who never or only rarely max out their service, the smaller wire is fine.  If you're continuously using your full capacity, they might give you a call about upgrading.

Comment: @markf  I couldn't believe the difference in connected load to actual demand. Heat loss was nothing but the smaller conductor weighs less and can span further, so it can eliminate pole guying and setting service poles close to your weather head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that and as you have noted, there are many used KWH meters for sale on EBAY and other places.  A properly installed meter base along with a listed meter will do what you want and be compliant.  It's not uncommon for such meters to be used with solar energy systems and such.

I recommend the old-fashioned mechanical kind vs. the new digital models.  They are simpler and more reliable in my opinion plus they look cool.  I like the spinning disk vs. a tiny LCD "spinning" one way or the other.

Comment: I've seen it done a lot. Just make sure you don't buy a meter  that was ripped off from the power co.  They can remove it without warning... and yes, the spinning disk was cool.  +1

Comment: The "Spinner" allows you get an "instantaneous" use measurement say when comparing several large loads. (Rotations per fixed time period)

Comment: @markf Yup, and you can do it on smart meters too if you read the documentation to figure out where they hid it :)